# Where do you put the type in Chapel variable declarations?

Tags: chapel

Where do you put the type in Chapel variable declarations?

More specifically, what’s the difference between `var a = 42: int;` and `var a: int = 42;`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Three basic background facts for this question:

1. Chapel's variable declaration syntax is: **var** *ident*: *type* = *init*;
2. Chapel supports compile-time type inference
3. In Chapel, `:` serves two roles:

   - as the type specifier or constraint when declaring new symbols
   - as the cast operator when applied to an expression

Given that, the declaration:

```
var a: int = 42;
```

says "declare a variable named `a`, whose type is `int` and whose initial value is 42."  Whereas,

```
var a = 42: int;
```

says "declare a variable named `a`, whose type (since it's not specified) will be inferred from its initializer, which is the value 42 cast to an `int`."

Now, in Chapel, `42` is interpreted as an `int` by default, so this final declaration is really no different than:

```
var a = 42;
```

and all three of the declarations above have the same net effect.

Things get slightly more interesting when you mix different types.  For example:

```
var b: int(8) = 42;
```

says that `b` should be an 8-bit integer whose initial value is 42.  In Chapel, even though the inferred type of 42 is `int` (which is a 64-bit int), since it is a literal value that can be represented in fewer than 8 bits, the compiler will automatically downcast it to fit into an int(8).

Or, the downcast could be made explicit, using the following form:

```
var b = 42: int(8);  // downcast to int(8) and infer the type
```

But consider:

```
var c: int(8) = a;
```

this will be an error because `a` is a default int variable (64 bits) and Chapel doesn't support implicit downcasts from variables of wider int representations to narrower ones.  So in this case, you'd need to write this declaration as one of the two forms:

```
var c = a: int(8);          // explicitly downcast and infer the type
var c: int(8) = a: int(8);  // give an explicit type and also explicitly downcast to make the initializer compatible
```

Needless to say, since this second form is a bit pedantic, we tend to prefer the former of the two.